# Dart: No Message specification for Exception?

Tags: exception, dart

I've been learning dart for a couple of weeks now, and I decided to work on a numeric vector class for practice purposes. This class requires a `UnequalVectorLengthException`.

I did my research into exceptions in dart, read the documentation, but I was surprised to find that there is no default method like `getMessage()`, like there is in java. I know you can add the message when throwing the exception, but I feel like there should a default message 'bound' to the exception instance that you could retrieve when catching it.
This leads me to think that an implementation could/should be:

```
class UnequalVectorLengthException implements Exception {}
```

which looks odd and incorrect to my java eye. Then the throwing would probably be:

```
if(stuff) throw UnequalVectorLengthException("Vectors are unequal length");
```

I've also seen people add extra methods like `String errorMessage() {}`, but since a user of that exception might not expect this method to exist, I don't think this is the go-to way to do this.

My question: is the above shown code the correct way to implement an exception in dart (in this case, a simple comment will do), or is there a better way to implement an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class definition looks fine. The `throw` line won't work since that class doesn't have a constructor that takes a String. The `message` argument to `Exception` is so that it can have a nice `.toString()` in the cases where you don't want to bother with creating a more specific type.

Not every subclass of `Exception` needs or should have a `message`. If one makes sense in a particular case then you can add it. In your example I wouldn't bother with a message because it's only repeating information already present in the class name.

```
class UnequalVectorLengthException implements Exception {
  @override
  String toString() => 'Vectors are unequal length';
}

if (stuff) throw UnequalVectorLengthException();
```

Comment: By the way, it is possible in simple cases / exploration code to [throw a string object directly](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#throw).